# ONLY IN condition for mapping table - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I have a mapping table which stores mapping between placements and products. [The table structure](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaa386/2) is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mapping_table (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  placement_id int NOT NULL,
  product_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO mapping_table (id, placement_id, product_name) VALUES
( 1, 2, 'product1'),
( 2, 1, 'product1'),
( 3, 2, 'product2'),
( 4, 1, 'product2'),
( 5, 2, 'product3'),
( 6, 4, 'product1'),
( 7, 2, 'product3'),
( 8, 4, 'product3'),
( 9, 1, 'product1'),
(10, 3, 'product1'),
(11, 4, 'product1'),
(12, 3, 'product2'),
(13, 4, 'product2'),
(14, 2, 'product1'),
(15, 4, 'product1'),
(16, 2, 'product3');
```

Now I need to select all the placements corresponds to `product 1` and `product 2`. It is possible that one placement can be mapped to multiple products. So a combination of `product 1 + product 2 + product 3` is possible and `product 1 + product 2` is also possible. I need to select placements which only assigned to `product 2` or `product 1` and not to `product 3` or any other products . When I use the IN() like the following query, it will give results including product3 also if there is such mapping. I would like to avoid those placements, which have product 3 in the mapping.

```
SELECT placement_id FROM mapping_table
WHERE product_name IN ('product1', 'product2') ;
```

What I need is

```
SELECT placement_id FROM mapping_table
WHERE product_name ONLY_IN ('product1', 'product2') AND NOT IN ('product3','product4', etc);
```

Comment: . . I am confused.  Do you want *both* products or *either* product.  You say both "all the placements corresponds to product 1 and product 2" and " select placements which only assigned to product 2 or product 1".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to check that each placement doesn't have a product which is not `product1` or `product2`:

```
SELECT DISTiNCT placement_id 
FROM mapping_table m1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM mapping_table m2
                  WHERE m2.placement_id = m1.placement_id
                    AND m2.product_name NOT IN ('product1', 'product2'));
```

Output

```
placement_id
1
3
```

Updated [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aaa386/15)

Comment: And how does this check that both products are in the placement?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it doesn't need to. It will eliminate any placements that have products which are not `product1` or `product2` thus leaving only placements which have either `product1` or `product2`, which is what OP asked for (`or`, not `and`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation with a special `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT placement_id
FROM mapping_table
GROUP BY placement_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN product_name     IN ('product1', 'product2') THEN 1 END) > 0
AND    COUNT(CASE WHEN product_name NOT IN ('product1', 'product2') THEN 1 END) = 0
```

(Earlier I assumed that you groups containing both products).

Answer (score 1):

A fun way in MySQL is:

```
SELECT placement_id
FROM mapping_table
GROUP BY placement_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_name ORDER BY product_name) = ('product1,product2');
```